# How to prevent opengl context loss when a new activity is loaded

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I am developing a 3d android app where i need to do rendering in two different activities( normal rendering in one activity and VR rendering in the other). I could find that once i move from one activity to another my 3d model data(vertices, indices) are being lost. If i come back to the first activity i have to reload the whole data from files. Is there any work around for this specific issue? Also which is the best format in which i could save the models to get the quickest loading speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GLSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(boolean)). While support for preserving EGL contexts is not guaranteed to be supported, it is widely available on modern Android devices.

As for model loading speed - you're treading dangerously into 'opinion based' territory. But, a model format laid out exactly as your GLES buffers expect on the device could be streamed directly from disk, without any modification - so, likely that would be your fastest loading solution. However, many developers use some other format (eg. FBX/OBJ/etc.), because they are more flexible and export directly from DCC tools.

Comment: Thanks, i could work around is preventing context loss. Moveover can suggest me some resources which can help me save the buffers directly into a file.